# Droplist in Excel using Poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, html-select, validation

How can I create a drop list in excel like drop list in html with the inbuilt "value" like attribute?

My Requirement is: I want to show the description which is not stored in database, but the code for description.

**Ex:** I have a subject list in an excel cell, for Science the description is "Science", but I want to store the code "SCI" in the Database.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ActiveX ComboBox in a worksheet, available from the Developers tab.

Enter both columns of data into the worksheet - you can hide the columns. Then set properties of the combobox:

- ColumnCount 2
- BoundColumn 1
- ColumnWidths 0 pt; 20 pt

Set the `ListFillRange` and `LinkedCell`.

I understand there used to be issues with distributing workbooks containing ActiveX controls. I am not sure if this is still an issue, particularly when used a common (standard) control.

Of course, Excel is not designed to be a front-end to a database, so you'll need to write all the code to keep everything in-sync.

You could use the simpler Form Control/ComboBox. This will only store the index number in a cell - it does not have any events that you can use. You could use a formula based on the linked cell, that stores the description in another cell. When the user (presumably) clicks a button to submit the data, you would retrieve and store the description from this cell.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I can see many **placeholder** occurs all around the web related to java poi... but it seems there is no solution for your question. The only way I found to manage this is to set the cell value with my default text - the first value!